# How many automatic searches per day can one do with google api account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

Is the limit the same 100 queries per day or is there a different arrangement?

Answer (score 1):

How many requests you can make against a Google api depends on a few things.

1. The api you are using.
2. The method you are calling with in that api.
3. The amount of quota you have.

No google api that i am aware of limits a specific method to only 100 per day, its more complicated and more like how many calls your quota allows you to make per day over the full api.